# Adding betting function to dice game and number guess game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a dice roll game on Python 3 but want to add a betting function.

I have tried a few things but I can only play one game. I want the game to have multiple rounds.

How do I make it a game where the player(s) can bet on multiple rounds until money ends at 0, or possibly keep playing until they want to stop?

```
import random
import time

print("this is a dice roll game")

def main():
  player1 = 0
    player1wins = 0
    player2 = 0
    player2wins = 0
    rounds = 1

    while rounds != 5:
        print("Round" + str(rounds))
        time.sleep(1)
        player1 = dice_roll()
        player2 = dice_roll()
        print("Player 1 rolled " + str(player1))
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Player 2 rolled " + str(player2))
        time.sleep(1)
        if player1 == player2:
            print("The round is a draw")
        elif player1 > player2:
            player1wins += 1
            print("Player 1 wins the round")
        else:
            player2wins += 1
            print("Player 2 wins the round")

        rounds = rounds + 1

    if player1wins == player2wins:
        print("The game ended in a draw")
    elif player1wins > player2wins:
        print("Player 1 wins the game, Rounds won: " + str(player1wins))
    else:
        print("Player 2 wins the game, Rounds won: " + str(player2wins))


def dice_roll():
    diceroll = random.randint(1,6)
    return diceroll

main()
```

Comment: Use a `while` loop? The question is rather broad (since there are many ways of doing something like this), but using a loop is a standard way of running code repeatedly. You could use `while True:` and then have a `return` when your exit condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the comment by John Coleman, you can modify your while loop so that it does not end when the number of rounds is different to 5, something like:

```
while True:
    // Rest of code...

    if moneyP1 <= 0 OR moneyP2 <=0:
        print("Someone ran out of money")
        // Implement deciding who won
        break
    user_confirmation = raw_input("Keep playing? (YES/NO): ")
    if user_confirmation == "NO":
        break
```